# Rails save unique token and secrets for different users (REST api)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, fitbit

I'm building an rails app with the fitgem (fitbit) api. Currently I can get it to work for one user by creating a .fitgem.yml file. I would like each user to get a unique .fitgem.yml file. How is this possible?

Thanks

.fitgem.yml

```
---
:oauth:
:consumer_key: [integers]
:consumer_secret: [integers]
:token: [integers]
:secret: [integers]
:user_id: [integers]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need one `.yml` per user? OAuth should be able to allow you to prompt user to log in to the provider, gain access token to read/write data for the user.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how I would do that?

Answer (score 1):

From the Fitbit docs,

Here is the OAuth workflow overview:

https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/OAuth+Authentication+in+the+Fitbit+API#OAuthAuthenticationintheFitbitAPI-TheOAuthFlow

- Basically, you register an application to consume Fitbit api, which would require you to pass consumer_key and request user data access. This would typically involve listing all the operations that the application needs to do.
- The provider then opens a prompt to the user to enter credentials and approve authorization to perform the above listed actions.
- Once the user signs in and authorizes, the provider gives an `auth_token` which the application needs to pass in every operation.

The `auth_token` can be set to expire after certain time, ensuring that the application does not get permanent access.

This way, your application does not need to store user credentials, and users are free to control access via the provider.

**Edit 1**

Ok, so in order to deal with OAuth providers, I have used [OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) gem to a great extent and have had no issues so far.

There is [OmniAuth Fitbit strategy](https://github.com/tkgospodinov/omniauth-fitbit), that should help you integrate Fitbit OAuth in your rails application.

Comment: I understand the overall process, but how do I give the user an auth_token in rails? where is it stored?